# How to pass https://achecker.ca/ validator?

Tags: code

[image]i have to pass https://achecker.ca/ validator for a client without any "known problems" an i recieved this message

Success Criteria 1.4.4 Resize text (AA)

Check 117: i (italic) element used.
Repair: Replace your i elements with em or strong.
Error Line 334, Column 8:

Error Line 415, Column 4:

What should i do? its very important

Comment: I'm no expert, but if I were you I would replace my `i` elements with `em` or `strong`.

Comment: `<i>` was used, in the past, for italics, but that's not standard any longer.  `<em>` is what you're supposed to use for 'emphasis`, it's just semantically correct code.  So either you've used `<i>italics</i>` in your content or some developer whose theme/plugin you're using is still using that as a fallback.  (Also `<b>` for bold has been replaced with `<strong>`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. It hasn’t identified an actual problem. It thinks you’re using an i tag for italics, but you’re not.

If you absolutely need the error to go away, you would need to find a way to get achecker to ignore the problem, and that's a question for them, rather than anything to do with WordPress.